# SSRS javascript window.open with special characters

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, window.open

is possible somehow create hyperlink to open new window in SSRS when the direct report name has special characters? (In my case Czech characters) - I use for encode the special chars function method of HttpUtility I added to the Reporting Services. I tried it and it encode correctly:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & Globals!ReportServerUrl & "?https://sharepoint.test.com/Reports/" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ReportName čí") & ".rdl&rs:command=render&rc:Toolbar=false&rs:ClearSession=True&rc:Parameters=true&pPARAMETERID=" & Fields!PARAMETERID.Value & "', '_blank', 'width=1000, height=1000, top=1, left=50,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1'))"
```

**Encoded report name is here and it is correct:**

Decoded:

> ReportName čí

Encoded:

> ReportName+%C4%8D%C3%AD

When the report is rendered I copied the rendered url from the report into IE browser and it works correctly. (When I inspected code of rendered Report HTML in IE Browser, the encoding still looks correctly).

But when I tried to click on the link directly in the report it failed and convert the characters into incorrect characters like this:

**The item 'https://sharepoint.test.com/Reports/ReportName ÃÂÃÂ­.rdl' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)**

I don't know if this is problem of Internet Explorer or directly SSRS, I cannot test it in different browser.

Thanks

Comment: If the URL you copied is correct and working (as you stated) then the issue is definitely not with SSRS (shouldn't be, since HttpUtility.UrlEncode uses UTF8 by default AFAIR, no matter on what system it runs).
The issue is definitely related to yet one strange aspect of the IE behavior, there're many examples of it.
Try to remove UrlEncode and use JS encodeURIComponent() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the function it is useful, but with the special characters it still doesn't work.

Comment: And I tried the SSRS report to run in Chrome and it works correctly so probably it is really problem of the IE.

Comment: What version of IE you've tested?